# Which GOARCH's should an opensource golang project test against?

Tags: go, travis-ci

I have an [opensource Go project](https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp). Some commits were causing failures on 386, but I didn't know because my builds were configured incorrectly.

I'm now testing against 386 using [Travis](https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/blob/master/.travis.yml). Which [GOARCH/GOOS/Go version combinations](https://gist.github.com/asukakenji/f15ba7e588ac42795f421b48b8aede63) should opensource projects test against? I want meaningful coverage but I also want fast builds.

Comment: If possible, include `Linux/amd64` in your test. From where I sit, I'd say most production Go code runs on that combo. But at the same time, I'd say SNMP could be of interest to enterprises which often use Windows for internal stuff. (On a side note: please fix the project's title: the language is called "Go", there is no such thing as "GoLang" except for a special keyword for searching via a particular Internet search engine.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see which Go binary release stable version combinations (Version/GOOS/GOARCH) are supported by Go downloads.

See [Go Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/)

---

You may limit it to Go first-class ports.

See [First class ports, PortingPolicy](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PortingPolicy).

---

You should conform to the Go release policy.

See [Release Policy, Go Release History](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html)

---

You should consider premptively testing against release candidates, and, perhaps betas and devel.

Comment: Thanks this is a great start! The list of 6 "first class ports" is linux/amd64,linux/386,linux/arm,darwin/amd64,windows/amd64,windows/386. Golang release policy says 3 major releases are supported. 6 * 3 (2+RC) = 18 cases. When I'm hacking stuff I'll cut this down to latest release and linux/amd64,linux/386 (2 cases) then test against all 18 cases. For the moment I'll just do this by editing .travis.yml, but I'm sure there's some magic I could do, testing a file for "quick" or "full". But that's another problem.

Comment: Consider including a simple test policy section in your README.md; it is often used an initial screen by interested users. Assume it's Cloudflare, which has a large network: [ARM Takes Wing: Qualcomm vs. Intel CPU comparison](https://blog.cloudflare.com/arm-takes-wing/). Intel and ARM CI testing for two current and any candidate Go releases might be important.

Comment: Good comment. I've added "builds tested against "linux/amd64, linux/386, darwin/amd64, windows/amd64, windows/386" near top of README. linux/arm is currently breaking with 'exec format error' :-(